# How to eliminate pain while performing half-pigeon?

Tags: yoga

I practice yoga fairly frequently -- a minimum of 2 times per week, usually Warm Vinyasa flow.  One pose that I have been unable to get comfortable in is half-pigeon, despite increased flexibility over the past year.  It's not just uncomfortable either, it's often painful in my knee and upper-hamstring area.  Could this be a problem with my leg positioning or something technical I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few adjustments you can try:

- elevate the pelvis, this will take some pressure off the knees
- bend the knees to full flexion
- move knee outwards if comfortable (bring the knee outside the line of the body)

If you still have pain or discomfort, try different versions/similar poses, [standing supported](https://yogainternational.com/assets/content/articles/Y165_11.jpg), [standing resting on other leg](http://www.110pounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/WL-STANDING-PIGEON-210x164.jpg), standing bent leg lift etc. Modify the pose so that less external force (bodyweight in this case) is applied.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The first two adjustments helped immensely. Thanks!